# How to tell if mouse pointer icon changed

Tags: windows, mouse, capture

I'm writing a screen recording app for Windows in Delphi 7 and wish to know when the mouse pointer changes in my app (like from a normal pointer to a resize pointer, etc).

Currently what I'm doing is painting the mouse pointer onto an in-memory bitmap everytime the mouse moves (and on a timer) and doing a pixel by pixel comparison of it with the last bitmap I painted.

Though the comparision is fairly quick (about 2-5ms) because it's happening so often (every mouse move) it adds up. I figure there has to be a faster and less complicated way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a handle to the cursor, right? If it's the same handle value you had before, then I think it's reasonable to assume it looks the same, too. If the cursor looks different, it will have a different handle value.

That should certainly be true for the standard system cursors. If the application you're recording is creating new cursors while it's running, then *maybe* it would be able to update the appearance of the current cursor without actually making a new cursor object in the OS (and thus keeping the same handle value), but I don't think that's likely, especially since `SetCursor` exits immediately when the cursor hasn't changed, and I expect the API function doesn't do the graphical comparison you're trying to avoid, either. It just compares the `HCursor` value.

Comment: I was wrong. I've started to notice simply checking the handle isn't enough as the handle only seems to change when hovering over my application. If I print the current cursor handle to screen every few ms while I hover over other apps it doesn't actually change when the cursor changes. :(

Comment: How are you getting the cursor handle when it's over another application? MSDN says to call GetCursorInfo instead of GetCursor.

Comment: Ahh right you are. I was comparing the results of GetCursor. Thanks again!