# C# - How to get current cursor state (if its currently arrow,hand,waiting etc)

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor

I tried to make a bot for one game, but they have cool anti pixel bot techniques.

So I thought, "If I can make a bot which only checks if cursor changes to hand and then click, its gonna work," because I am gonna need to collect bonus boxes, and when you point your cursor at it, it changes to "hand" cursor.

So I was so happy about this idea, but in C#, it's not working!

In C# - `Cursor.Current` only checks for cursor state on form and not in whole computer, which is not what I want.

So, how could I get real cursor-type state? (If it's hand, normal cursor, sizing something or waiting etc)

Comment: The answer was copy and paste from [jitbit][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457069/get-current-mouse-cursor-type

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found something and made it working, heres the code if anyone needed this :

```
    private static string GetCursorState()
    {
        var h = Cursors.WaitCursor.Handle;

        CURSORINFO pci;
        pci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO));
        GetCursorInfo(out pci);


        return pci.hCursor.ToString();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct POINT
    {
        public Int32 x;
        public Int32 y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct CURSORINFO
    {
        public Int32 cbSize;        // Specifies the size, in bytes, of the structure. 
        // The caller must set this to Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO)).
        public Int32 flags;         // Specifies the cursor state. This parameter can be one of the following values:
        //    0             The cursor is hidden.
        //    CURSOR_SHOWING    The cursor is showing.
        public IntPtr hCursor;          // Handle to the cursor. 
        public POINT ptScreenPos;       // A POINT structure that receives the screen coordinates of the cursor. 
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CURSORINFO pci);
```

Comment: you can get cursor-ID by using idk.. timer and for example "this.Text = GetCursorState().ToString()" .. enjoy