# "Listener" for detect changes on mouse icon

Tags: delphi

I seen here a code that retrieves the current icon of mouse as string, but this code had uses a `TTimer` for make it.

So, i want know if exist some event (Listener) for detect these change on mouse cursor icon.

Below is code that uses a `TTimer`:

```
const
  HighCursor = 13;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCursorHandles: array [0..HighCursor] of HCURSOR;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  OEMCursors: array [0..HighCursor] of Integer = (OCR_NORMAL, OCR_IBEAM,
      OCR_WAIT, OCR_CROSS, OCR_UP, OCR_SIZENWSE, OCR_SIZENESW, OCR_SIZEWE,
      OCR_SIZENS, OCR_SIZEALL, OCR_NO, OCR_HAND, OCR_APPSTARTING,
      32651 {OCR_HELP?});

  CursorNames: array [0..HighCursor] of string = ('OCR_NORMAL', 'OCR_IBEAM',
      'OCR_WAIT', 'OCR_CROSS', 'OCR_UP', 'OCR_SIZENWSE', 'OCR_SIZENESW',
      'OCR_SIZEWE', 'OCR_SIZENS', 'OCR_SIZEALL', 'OCR_NO', 'OCR_HAND',
      'OCR_APPSTARTING', 'OCR_HELP');

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to HighCursor do
    FCursorHandles[i] := LoadImage(0, MakeIntResource(OEMCursors[i]),
        IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR or LR_DEFAULTSIZE or LR_SHARED);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

  function GetCursorName(Cursor: HCURSOR): string;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to HighCursor do
      if Cursor = FCursorHandles[i] then begin
        Result := CursorNames[i];
        Exit;
      end;
    Result := 'Unknown Cursor';  // A custom cursor.
  end;

var
  CursorInfo: TCursorInfo;
begin
  CursorInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(CursorInfo);
  if GetCursorInfo(CursorInfo) then
    Label1.Caption := GetCursorName(CursorInfo.hCursor)
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'Fail: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
end;
```

Comment: There's no point in doing what you ask. The mouse cursor is something a program _can **optionally**_ change to give the user a visual clue about what the program is doing or what the user can/cannot do. The cursor is in fact a duplication of state information, and a very common bug is that the cursor does not always accurately reflect the internal state of the program. Even when you've determined what the state of the cursor is, that information is somewhat meaningless. So, the question is: _What is your **real** problem?_ (You should post your real problem as a new question.)

Comment: PS: Note that even position of the cursor on the desktop/window can affect what icon is used.

Comment: [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4184046/243614).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that applications listen for events is via Windows messages. There is no message sent when the cursor image is changed, so there is nothing to listen for; your code using a timer is the only possibility.

See [Cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646970(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN for the functions and notifications that Windows provides for cursors.

Comment: Indeed, I can't imagine any logical reason why any app would even care when the cursor has changed - other than apps which wish to change it back.