# How change the mouse cursor inside a control?

Tags: delphi

I have a Remote Access similar to Team View software and I want change the mouse cursor ( on "Controler" part, server side in other words ) according with icon of mouse of "Controled" part, like was done in Team View software.

My software is using a `TPaintBox` because I need make others thing that is necessary a `TPaintBox` for work fine.

`TPaintBox` has `crDefault` as default cursor. How can I change this ( on "Controler" part ) only while mouse is inside the `TPaintBox`?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185470/listener-for-detect-changes-on-mouse-icon?noredirect=1#comment65719734_39185470) is code used for capture icon of mouse in "Controled" part ( client side ).

And here is my code until now trying change icon of mouse in "Controler" part ( server side ):

```
//pbRec is name of TPaintBox used

procedure TForm2.pbRecMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Form2.lblPoint.Caption = 'OCR_NORMAL' then
    pbRec.Cursor := crDefault
  else if Form2.lblPoint.Caption = 'OCR_HAND' then
    pbRec.Cursor := crHandPoint
  else if Form2.lblPoint.Caption = 'OCR_IBEAM' then
    pbRec.Cursor := crIBeam;
end;
```

All suggestions will welcome.

Comment: Use the PaintBox's OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you tried, how does it fail?

Comment: Ask a new question about sending real time messages between a client and a server. I hope you agree I've answered your question how to change the cursor. (SO does not allow asking 2 questions in a single post).

Comment: this is strange. you are setting the cursor property in your code. the answer you accepted is doing the same. i wonder what was your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the cursor in code the following will work.

```
//Context: Timer.Interval = 50; :-)

procedure TForm57.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: TPoint;
begin
  if Ord(PaintBox1.Cursor) < Ord(crSizeAll) then PaintBox1.Cursor:= crArrow
  else PaintBox1.Cursor:= Pred(PaintBox1.Cursor);
  //Force Windows to change the cursor by sending a WM_SETCURSOR message.
  PaintBox1.Parent.Perform(WM_SETCURSOR, PaintBox1.Parent.Handle, MakeLParam(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE)); 
  (** //if you're viewing using a slow remote connection you make need to do this: 
  //Wiggle the mouse to force cursor change.
  GetCursorPos(p);
  SetCursorPos(p.x-1, p.y);
  Sleep(100); //needed on slow remote connection.
  SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y);  (**)
end;
```

If you're going to change the cursor based on some context every time the mouse enters the paintbox it's rather wasteful to do this in the MouseMove event.
Change it in the `OnMouseEnter` event instead.

```
procedure TForm57.PaintBox1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if .... then PaintBox1.Cursor:= crIBeam
  else if .....
  PaintBox1.Parent.Perform(WM_SETCURSOR, PaintBox1.Parent.Handle, MakeLParam(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE));
end;
```

If you're on a remote connection then the client remote-side may cache the cursor. In that case you may need to wiggle it one side, `Sleep(100)` and wiggle it back for the client software to detect a mouse move and force a cursor refresh.

If you just want the cursor inside the `PaintBox` to be static, but different from the rest of the app then this works just fine:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to wiggle the mouse. You can replace the last three lines with `PaintBox1.Parent.Perform(WM_SETCURSOR, PaintBox1.Parent.Handle, MakeLParam(HTCLIENT, WM_MOUSEMOVE));`

Comment: @Johan, I want change cursor ( on server side) only when client side say me that cursor was changed sending actual cursor to `lblPoint` ( TLabel ) on server side, and according with this `TLabel` I can change in server side for actual cursor showing on client side  :-)

Comment: I can't make sense of what you're saying. Unless you're doing VLC the server and client each have their own mouse and cursor. If you're talking about sending messages between a client and a server that's a different question.

Comment: @Johan, yes, client sends actual cursor to server and I want change cursor  of server to be equal client cursor.

Comment: So change the cursor of server to be equal to the client cursor then. Which part can't you do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, So, where and how make it while mouse of server stays inside a `TPaintBox`?

Comment: @Sormanne, comments are not for asking new questions. I recommend asking a new question. Interrogating David will not work, because the comments don't provide enough space for the answer :-).

Comment: @Johan, based in your answer solve my trouble. Thank you very much! :D